# Get Visual Studio Code to give intellisense for custom Javascript imports

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, testcomplete

I am writing automated testing scripts using TestComplete.  TestComplete mostly supports Ecmascript 2015, but it has a few quirks that are causing intellisense to not work as I would expect.

Here is two examples of code files:

**File: *UsefulStuffFileName.js***

```
class UsefulStuff {
    constructor(initValue) {
        this.initValue = initValue;
    }

    get someValue(){
        return this.initValue + " someValue";
    }

    doStuff(input) {
        return input + " stuff done";
    }
}

module.exports.UsefullStuff = UsefullStuff;
```

**File: *WorkingHere.js***

```
var useful = require('UsefulStuffFileName');

class WorkingHere {
    constructor() {
        this.usefullStuff = new useful.UsefulStuff("Hello");
    }

    doCoolStuff() {
        // I want intellisense options when I type the period after this.usefulStuff
        // The options would be someValue, doStuff() and initValue.
        //                                |
        //                                |
        //                                V
        let myVariable = this.usefullStuff.someValue;                
    }
}
```

The quirks, as I see them are:

1. The export is done via this style: `module.exports.UsefullStuff = UsefullStuff;`.  (This makes it work with TestComplete.)
2. The "import" assigns to a variable (`var useful = require('UsefulStuffFileName');`)
3. The "new"ing of the object uses the variable to access the class (`new useful.UsefulStuff("Hello");`).

**Is there anyway to configure Visual Studio Code to understand how these files are related and give me intellisense?**

Note: If I try the more standard `import {UsefulStuff} from './UsefulStuffFileName';` I get an error saying "Unexpected token import" from TestComplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via these steps.

1. Change the import to look like this:

   `var { UsefulStuff } = require('UsefulStuff');`
2. Change the instantiation of the class to look like this:

   `this.usefulStuff = new UsefulStuff("Hello");`
3. Add a file called `jsconfig.json` and put this in it:

.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "."      
    }
}
```